# Can I use same stock broker to buy stocks from different stock markets?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, broker

I'm a college student and new to stocks investment. I wonder if I can use same stock broker to buy stocks from different stock markets? e.g. NYSE and NASDAQ

If yes, can I use the broker in US to buy stocks from other countries?

Or if the answer simply depends on different brokers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US there is only one stock market (ignoring penny stocks) and handfuls of different exchanges behind it.  NYSE and NASDAQ are two different exchanges, but all the products you can buy on one can also be bought on the other; i.e. they are all the same market.  So a US equities broker cannot possibly restrict access to any "markets" in the US because there is only one.

(Interestingly, it is commonplace for US equity brokers to cheat their customers by using only exchanges where they -- the brokers -- get the best deals, even if it means your order is not executed as quickly or cheaply as possible.  This is called `payment for order flow` and unfortunately will probably take an Act of Congress to stop.)

Some very large brokers will have trading access to popular equity markets in other countries (Toronto Stock Exchange, Mexico Stock Exchange, London Stock Exchange) and can support your trades there.  However, at many brokers or in less popular foreign markets this is usually **not** the case; to trade in the average foreign country you typically must open an account with a broker in that country.

Comment: All exchanges are part of a country's stock market, including penny stocks.  Your description of NYSE and NASDAQ products being available on both exchanges is incorrect.  Brokers can restrict client access to various securities and strategies (options, Bulletin Board stocks, margin, shorting, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Most stock brokers are "full service" brokers. That is to say that you can so the same broker to buy different types of stocks, bonds, options, etc. in different markets.

Some brokers are very specialized and won't allow you to do that. But those are probably brokers you don't want to use.